# How can I get the parent category group via the category to create multiple relation criteria?

Tags: categories, relations

I have two category groups: `Cars` and `Colors`

My `Cars` category looks like this:

```
Cars
    Sports Cars
        Corvette
        Lamborghini
        Porche
```

My `Colors` category looks like this:

```
Colors
    Red
    Black
    White
```

I have two drop-down menus; one to choose the car, the other to choose the color.

I can choose the car, or the color just fine. My url's look like this:

```
mysite.com/cars/corvette/
- or - 
mysite.com/cars/red/
```

It's when I need to relate *both* categories. Since my two category groups have different levels, I'm not sure how to get the parent group of `Colors` from `red`. Which is what I think I need in order for the `relatedTo` to work properly.

For example, a url might look like this:

```
mysite.com/cars/corvette/  {# no problem #}  
- or - 
mysite.com/cars/red/       {# no problem #}
```

I'm able to get to the categories on my template:

```
{# 
 # Get the primary category GROUP via url segment. 
 # Example: Cars
 #
 #}
{% set primaryCategoryGroup = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}

{#
 # Get the primary CATEGORY via url segment.
 # Ex: Corvette or Red
 #}
{% set primaryCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}
```

Then I check if I need to compare both relationships:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(4)|length %}
      {% set secondaryCategorySlug = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(4)) %}
      {% set secondaryCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(4)).first() %}

      {{ secondaryCategory.title }}  {# Red or Corvette #}
      {{ primaryCategory }}  {# Red or Corvette #}

      {# Begin the fail #}
      {% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo('and',
          { sourceElement: secondaryCategory, field:'title' },
          { targetElement: primaryCategory }
      ) %}
{% else %}
    {# Only get single relationship. #}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(primaryCategory) %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is correct, but this works.

Example urls:

```
www.mysite.com/cars/corvette/red
www.mysite.com/cars/red/corvette
...
www.mysite.com/cars/red/
www.mysite.com/cars/corvette
```

Here is my template:

```
{#
 # Check if there are multiple url segments to compare against.
 # This means we need to check against multiple relationships.
 # Ex: All Corvettes that are also Red
 #
 #}
{% if craft.request.getSegment(4)|length %}
    {% set secondaryCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(4)).first() %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(['and', { targetElement: primaryCategory }, { targetElement: secondaryCategory }]) %}
{% else %}
    {#
     # Get all products related to the current category.
     # Ex: All Sports Cars that are related to Corvettes.
     #
     #}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(primaryCategory) %}
{% endif %}

...

{% if entries|length %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

What i'm not sure about is both are using `targetElement` instead of one being `sourceElement`.